# Regex matching all the occurrences

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I brought till

```
instance_name(.+)(?=instance_name)
```

My Test String:

```
instance_name DEDUP

iops,other,1

instance_name USERSPACE_APPS

iops,read,158534981

iops,write,168514545

iops,other,1557566878

total_latency,read,38774076988

total_latency,write,36596756500

total_latency,other,96023066014

time
```

It matches only

```
DEDUP

iops,other,1
```

I understand that there is no instance_name at the end. But I want to match all the data after instance_name till the next instance_name. But for the last occurrence, There is no instance_name at the end. I want that as well.

I am using python. Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

Expected output:

Match1:

```
DEDUP

    iops,other,1

Match2: 
USERSPACE_APPS

    iops,read,158534981

    iops,write,168514545

    iops,other,1557566878

    total_latency,read,38774076988

    total_latency,write,36596756500

    total_latency,other,96023066014
```

Comment: Use dotall mode and the lazy quantifier: `instance_name(.+?)(?=instance_name)`

Comment: @Jan I used DOT ALL mode. If I add laze quantifier, it is not matching the last occurrence because there is not instance name at the end

Comment: Which is the last occurance? Can you specify what exactly you want the regex to match ?

Comment: @Himaprasoon please see the edit

Comment: Change it to `instance_name(.+?)(?=instance_name|\Z)` then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to

```
instance_name(.+?)(?=instance_name|\Z)
```

This adds an alternation (`|`) where `\Z` means the very end of the string (posted from mobile hence a bit short).

Comment: If you explain a bit, it would be nice answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by Jan didn't work for me and I don't think it will work for any more 'instance_name' values added to the text, however this did:

```
(?:(?<=instance_name\s)(?<value>(?:.|\s)*?)(?=instance_name\s|$))*
```

Explination (from the inside out):

```
(?<value>(?:.|\s)*?)
```

This is the group that will be the match you want. The `?<value>` part can be removed as I only added it for reference in this documentation

```
(?<=instance_name\s)
```

Only match if the group 'value' is preceded with the string literal 'instance_name' followed by a whitespace (space,tab,newline)

```
(?=instance_name\s|$)
```

Only match if the group 'value' is followed by either the string literal 'instance_name' or by the end of the string

```
(?: <all regex from above> )*
```

Wrap the matching conditions above in a new non-capturing group, as we might want to repeat the search for multiple 'instance_name' searches in the string

Hope this helps you out :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really want to do here is just to *split* your string:

```
>>> s = '''instance_name DEDUP
... 
... iops,other,1
... 
... instance_name USERSPACE_APPS
... 
... iops,read,158534981
... 
... iops,write,168514545
... 
... iops,other,1557566878
... 
... total_latency,read,38774076988
... 
... total_latency,write,36596756500
... 
... total_latency,other,96023066014
... 
... time'''
>>> s.split('instance_name')
['',
 ' DEDUP\n\niops,other,1\n\n',
 ' USERSPACE_APPS\n\niops,read,158534981\n\niops,write,168514545\n\niops,other,1557566878\n\ntotal_latency,read,38774076988\n\ntotal_latency,write,36596756500\n\ntotal_latency,other,96023066014\n\ntime']
```

If you want to remove empty strings and white space:

```
>>> list(filter(bool, (chunk.strip() for chunk in s.split('instance_name'))))
['DEDUP\n\niops,other,1',
 'USERSPACE_APPS\n\niops,read,158534981\n\niops,write,168514545\n\niops,other,1557566878\n\ntotal_latency,read,38774076988\n\ntotal_latency,write,36596756500\n\ntotal_latency,other,96023066014\n\ntime']
```

If `instance_name` in your specific case is not a fixed string, but it's a pattern, then you can use [`re.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split).